# What does muddy transmission fluid indicate?

Tags: chevrolet, diagnostics, transmission-fluid, 4l60e, lumina

I'm in the process of pulling out the engine & transmission from my Lumina (progress [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51715/zaids-lumina-diary)).

The picture below shows the state of the transmission fluid. It has a slightly grainy texture to it.

[image: Muddy transmission fluid]

I don't recall facing an issue with shifting gears (this is the 4L60E automatic transmission), which has around 90k miles on it.

***Does this fluid tell me anything about the state of the transmission?***

Comment: How long has the vehicle been sitting since you parked it?

Comment: Could be coolant. Fill a water bottle with it and let it sit overnight (a few hours may be sufficient). Any coolant in there will separate and settle at the bottom. The foolproof way is to send some away for analysis, but this is a quick and easy way to see if there definitely is.